# Testing absolute URLS Before The Website is Live

Tags: html, web-testing

Is there a way to test absolute urls before a site is live? (probably a stupid question, but gotta learn somewhere)

For example, website is called http://www.newwebsite.com

Building the site with links coded like `<li><a href="http://www.newwebsite.com/page1/">Page 1</a></li>`

Is there anyway of testing the links all work, without the site actually being live?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on how exactly you are testing your site before it is “live” ... And btw., I would avoid full absolute URLs wherever possible. There is usually no reason why this link should not just be `/page1/` in the first place.

Comment: use relative links, deploy on localhost, done.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Without being live as in no uploaded to its final server, that would make it live on the internet. I did use relative initially in which case search engine preview works. Switched to absolute after reading it they were better... perhaps not then :(